# How to remove Navigator.Webdriver flag in Selenium Chrome 104

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, navigator

I was wondering how I can change the `Navigator.Webdriver` boolean to `false` in Chrome 104 using selenium.

I tried some old methods but they all seem to be for chrome 94 and below. I tried the first method listed here, but got execution errors related to chrome version: https://piprogramming.org/articles/How-to-make-Selenium-undetectable-and-stealth--7-Ways-to-hide-your-Bot-Automation-from-Detection-0000000017.html

Answer (score 0):

To set **`navigator.webdriver`** as *`None`* / *`undefined`* you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
  driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
  print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.webdriver;"))

  # Setting navigator.webdriver as undefined
  driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
  print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.webdriver;"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  True
  None
  ```

Comment: Hello. I decided to install Chrome 79x instead, since it's more used in tutorial video's I want to watch. The code `option.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
` actually end up working fine.